# Conditional Logic to show or hide fields in the admin?

Tags: entries, categories, conditional, logic

I'm looking for a way to show or hide fields when editing an entry based on items selected.

I need to manage a list of businesses and my plan is to have a channel to hold them all. But based on the type of business, there are different pieces of information I need to collect.

- They all have common attributes (Name, Description, Location, Phone, etc.)
- There are many types (Restaurant, Recreation, Venue, etc.)

  - Many types have subtypes, but not all (Restaurant: American, Chinese, Casual)
  - Some have additional Info based on their type (Venu includes a list of meeting rooms with Names, Dimensions, Amenities, etc.)
  - Businesses can have more than one type (Restaurant, Venu)

What I'd like to do is be able to show different sets of inputs based on what categories are selected.

- Check Restaurant

  - Reveal a list of Restaurant types, because that is relevant only to restaurants.
- Check Venue

  - Reveal a table field type so you can enter a list of room names with corresponding features and amenities.

Is there a way in Craft, or is there a plugin that lets you run logic based on inputs to show or hide other inputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the **Reasons** plugin... sounds like exactly what you need:

> https://github.com/mmikkel/Reasons-Craft/

Comment: I'm too slow!!!

Comment: Beat you by 14 seconds :)

Comment: Perfect! Looks like exactly what I need. Winner gets the checkmark!

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing native, but this is the [highest requested feature](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7185745-conditionals-in-field-layouts) on the feedback site!

And there is also [this plugin](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/reasons), which might do what you're looking for.